# HTML button links do not work on mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, button

I would really appreciate it if anyone could give me a hand with this issue?

I am working on a wordpress site currently, having added my own code to the header top area - action bar. The buttons work fine on desktop however when scaled down to mobile the link shortens and is squashed to the right or lefthand side depending on the right and left buttons.

I've taken note that the padding of the templates wrapper or container, is probably the issue as this is the area it is covering. However I do not know how to fix it as it won't change as easily as expected.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="http://joyskipper.co.uk/food-styling-recipe-development/"><div style="width:100px;background-color: #F6A000;text-align:center;float:left;padding:10px;margin:10px;color:#fff;">FOOD</div></a>
```

And an example of the padding on the container causing the issue
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka7Gd.png)

I would prefer if the buttons kept the link around the box rather than just the text.

This is the site it is used on http://www.joyskipper.co.uk/nutrition/

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give like this it may work

```
<a href="http://joyskipper.co.uk/food-styling-recipe-development/" style="width:100px;background-color: #F6A000;text-align:center;float:left;padding:10px;margin:10px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;">
<div >FOOD</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give Anchor tag to inline-style or class which property should display block

like this:

```
<a href="#." style="display:block;">  Lorem ipsum </a>

.block-tag {
   display:block;
}
<a href="#." class="block-tag"> Lorem ipsum </a>
```